# Special Binary Tree, a tricky questions?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, tree, binary-tree

We have a binary tree with `n` nodes. this tree is not necessarily balanced.  for any node such `x` of this tree, we calculate the size (i.e: number of nodes) of `left` and `right` subtree of this node and set the label of this node as the `minimum` of these two values (values of right size and left size subtree). if any subtree has zero nodes, this size is equal to `0`. Which of the following is True:

I) sum of labels belongs to order `O(n log n)`.

II) there is a tree that sum of it's label belongs to order `O(n)`. (i.e: is it possible to get a tree with sum of it's label be O(n)?)

III) there is a tree that sum of it's label belongs to order `O(n^2)`.

My TA says two of these is true. My problem is with these sentences, anyone could describe it for me?

Comment: One analytical technique is to start with simple cases.  Then extend it by one for all possible cases.  If you do not find a pattern, extend it again.  But any computer science student should know (2) is obviously ...

Comment: for expert like you @Jerry it's obvious. not for me. thanks anyway

Comment: @SaraPhD What's the sum of labels for a balanced tree? What's the sum of labels for a maximally unbalanced tree?

Comment: @PaulHankin Log n?

Comment: Have you tried drawing them on paper or are you just guessing?

Comment: @o9000 balanced tree like as heap, at most O(log n). it's obvious

Comment: @SaraPhD all the non-leaf nodes have label at least 1 in a balanced tree, and there's approximately n/2 non-leaf nodes. So the sum of labels in a balanced tree is at least n/2 -- and so is provably not O(log n).

Comment: You really shouldn't solve these problems without drawing the trees.

Comment: @PaulHankin your argument is very nice !!

Comment: I think the statements are badly written. Some of them need Θ instead of O. Aslo, "there is a tree" makes no sense in context of asymptotic bounds, we need to talk about an infinite family of trees.

Comment: I'm not trying to be sarcastic, but you may slap your forehead when understanding the analysis of (2).  Anyhow, your first sentence says the tree is not necessarily balanced, but the discussion seems focused on a balanced tree.  I also suggest drawing some trees, both balanced and unbalanced.

Comment: @Jerry I agree with you. this is very tricky question...

Comment: Are you agreeing that you should draw some trees to analyze?  Has that helped?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it's 1 & 2.

1.) Consider the height of the tree. The height and the number of nodes n have the relationship n = (2^h)-1. From this relation, we can derive that h =logn. Now, Let's move to the number of nodes in each level of the binary tree. The maximum number of nodes that a level *could* have is (n/2) which is the last level (in a full binary tree, the last level will have n/2 nodes). So, the worst case of calculating the minimum is (number of levels)*(number of nodes in each level) => n/2logn => O(nlogn).

2.) It's possible to get an 0(n) solution by changing the height of the tree. For example of if considering a *subset* of the all nodes such that the height of the tree is zero/one, then it's possible to get an O(n) solution - for a tree with a total level of two, there can be a maximum of three nodes (root, left, right), and therefore, there's no minimum calculation involved in this. In this case, we don't have the additional logn in running time, and we end up with O(n).

Comment: maybe there is counterexample or proof for (3), I think this is a nice question.

Comment: which part of the second is not underestand?

Comment: @SaraPhD I've tried to add more information. Hope this helps.

Comment: How we can sure about (3) ?

Comment: @SaraPhD  With (1), I'm saying that it takes O(nlogn) time. So it doesn't make sense to me that we'd want to handle the same problem with a worse running time (O(nlogn) is better than O(n^2)).

Comment: you means with showing (1) is correct, (3) should be wrong?

Comment: @SaraPhD Yes. Because what we're getting with (1) is already better than (3)

Comment: sorry for my last question, I know it's better but what is the proof for (3)? this is my misunderstand point.

Comment: Please see above comment by Jerry

Comment: @SaraPhD I'm sorry. I don't have a concrete proof for (3). I'd just say that (3) contradicts (1) if (1) is true.

Comment: If you want to (dis)prove (3), standard technique is showing analysis of all possible cases.  Start by drawing a tree of height 1.  What happens at height 2? 3? n?